# Printing JSON data using php

Tags: php, json

I have used the code below to return JSON array from php code.

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$query="select *from college_notice";
$run=mysql_query($query);
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($run))
{
$output[]=$data;

echo (json_encode($output));
}
mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

But it displays array shown below:

[{"0":"6","id":"6","1":"Bijay","notice":"Bijay","2":"2015-08-24 08:06:59","date":"2015-08-24 08:06:59"}][{"0":"6","id":"6","1":"Bijay","notice":"Bijay","2":"2015-08-24 08:06:59","date":"2015-08-24 08:06:59"},{"0":"7","id":"7","1":"Subash","notice":"Subash","2":"2015-08-24 08:11:13","date":"2015-08-24 08:11:13"}]

Is my output correct or not??

Comment: No, that does not validate, you can use jsonlint.org to validate a JSON string

Comment: @bub _You could collect the data into $data[]_ I think you should take a second look.

Comment: Do not call `json_encode` *insde* your loop.  Build the *complete* array you want, then `echo json_encode($output)` at the end of the script.  You need to generate/echo *one* JSON string, not multiple.

Comment: Thank you Rocket,, It worked after i used json_encode outdside the loop..

Answer (score 3):

You should move the `echo (json_encode($output));` outside the loop like this

```
<?php
   include("connect.php");
   $query="select *from college_notice";
   $run=mysql_query($query);
   while($data=mysql_fetch_array($run))
   {
      $output[]=$data;
   }

   echo json_encode($output);

   mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

You also dont need the `()` around it. Wont cause it to stop working but it is unnecessary and looks odd.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand JSON and array are two different things.
Your output looks correct - *in case of json format*.

**JSON is JavaScript Object Notation**

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for machines to parse and generate. It is based on a subset of the JavaScript Programming Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition - December 1999. JSON is a text format that is completely language independent but uses conventions that are familiar to programmers of the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Perl, Python, and many others. These properties make JSON an ideal data-interchange language.

More:

- http://json.org/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

**Arrays**

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that
>   associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several
>   different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash
>   table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack,
>   queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees
>   and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

More:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: **Correct?** apart from the fact that it is wrong. **not my idea of correct**

Comment: I said in case of json format, I didn't check syntax. Updated my answer.

Comment: Well actually you just edited that in, so no you didn't